# Unable to place the cursor position dynamically in cics

Tags: cursor-position, cics

I have a map which has only one input field where the user will choose the option from 3 given options. I haven't used IC in the attribute definition of the field in map. What i've done is before sending the map, I used this statement: MOVE -1 TO OPTIONL which I thought is used to place the cursor in this option field. But this isn't working. What might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify CURSOR without a position value? Even though you set the length attribute to -1, the CURSOR positioning option on SEND MAP must be specified - but without a value. Something like

```
  MOVE -1 TO OPTIONL
  EXEC CICS SEND
     MAP('MYMAP'),
     MAPSET('MYMAPSET')
     CURSOR
     ERASE
  END-EXEC
```